# Android get need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme error when app based on AppCompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme, illegalstateexception

I'm trying to show AlterDialog on Fragment by this code, but i get error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Views.Activities.Main.ActivityMain"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"/>
```

Style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/signal_toolbar_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/signal_secondary_color</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>
```

how can i resolve this problem? my ActivityMain style is based on AppCompat and i wondering why cause of i get this problem

## UPDATE:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_allow, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                request.proceed();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.button_deny, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                request.cancel();
            }
        })
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setMessage(messageResId)
        .show();
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the Java code for the `AlertDialog`.

Comment: change parent theme in style to some other ,it should work

Comment: OK, what's `context` exactly? That is, how are you setting it?

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks. problem resolved by change context to getActivity() sir